# Implementing autocompletion to zsh aliases

Tags: bash, zsh, bash-completion, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I am using the awesome zsh framework [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). Every day I hit `gc` which is an alias for `git commit` I hit `<Tab><Tab>` and it gives me the correct files to commit. I am really interested to know how that is implemented, so I can implement my own idea of navigating to sub-directories using an alias.

I mean navigating into `~/workspace/a-repo` using this alias `-w a<Tab><Tab>` which completes to `a-repo` and gives me some suggestions which are folders inside `~/workspace`. I made this alias already but I need to know how to add the correct autocompletion/suggestion to it.

Here is my alias:

```
-w() { cd ~/workspace/"$*" }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `gc` (which I assume is defined as `alias gc='git commit -v'` in the git plugin of *oh-my-zsh*) `zsh` internally substitutes the alias (`gc`) with the actual command (`git commit -v` ) before looking for trying for completions. This works for every alias (unless the shell option `COMPLETE_ALIASES` is set, which would allow to set separate completions for aliases).

As for what you want to do: Seing that `-w` is actually a function and not an alias, you indeed would have to write your own completion. But there is a much simpler way to go about it: *Static named directories*.

*Named directories* are usually just the home directories of the users on the system. The most commonly known is probably `~` for the home directory of the current user. Other users directories are named `~USERNAME`. You can also define your own *static named directories*. There are two ways to do this:

- Use `hash -d` to explicitly define a name, similar to an alias:

```
hash -d w=~/workspace
```

- Implicitly define it by defining a string shell parameter whose value begins with an `/` (this also means you cannot use `~` as shortcut for your home directory)

```
w="${HOME}/workspace"
```

In both cases you now can use `~w` to reference your workspace, in the second case you can also use `$w` (for example for use in quoted strings). Typing `cd ~w/a-repo` will get you to `~/workspace/a-repo`. Tab-completion works like it would with any other path, so pressing `~w/a<Tab>` will present you `~w/a-repo` as completion.

Additionally, if you set the shell option AUTO_CD (`setopt AUTO_CD`), you can switch into a directory just by typing the path (or directory name) without the need for `cd`.

```
% w="/tmp"
% cd ~w
% pwd
/tmp
% mkdir 1 2 3
% setopt AUTO_CD
% ~w/<TAB>
1 2 3
% ~w/1
% pwd
/tmp/1
```